# detect native/stock Android browser User Agent string via PHP

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile, webkit, css-transitions

I am getting a *lot* of JavaScript errors on the native/stock Android 4.1 browser **only** and I would like to detect the User Agent string via PHP.

I use the [Mobile_Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) library to check for OS, devices and browsers, however it does not support detecting the native Android browser.

There are numerous posts on SO regarding this topic, but not answer it would seem.

I am getting a lot of errors stating:

```
Cannot set property 'webkitTransitionDelay'
Cannot set property 'webkitTransform'
```

...so I would like to switch jQuery Mobile page transitions **off** for this browser - but I need to have the ability to detect it first.

Is there a way to detect it? I must stress it's not the OS I want to detect, it's the native browser (also called Android).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following:

```
(preg_match('/^Mozilla\/5\.0.*Android\s[12]\..*\sMobile/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) 
    && !preg_match('/\sChrom/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
```

To match Android Browser on older Android platforms (1.x or 2.x) (which [don't support SVG](http://caniuse.com/svg)).

- 'Chrom' to exclude both 'Chrome' and 'Chromium' (the latter might not exist)
- Firefox currently doesn't include the Android version which means it isn't positively matched above. I've added an explicit exclusion for it below in case it starts to add the Android version number

A few test strings:

**Older Android Browser**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; en-gb; SAMSUNG GT-I9100/I9100BUKJ3 Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

**Chrome on Android**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.59 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**Firefox on Android**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:26.0) Gecko/26.0 Firefox/26.0
```

**Opera Mini on Android**

```
Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/7.5.33361/34.788; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; en-gb; GT-I9100 Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Any version of the Android Browser + excluding Firefox:

```
(preg_match('/^Mozilla\/5\.0.*Android\s\d\..*\sMobile/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) 
    && !preg_match('/\sChrom/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    && !preg_match('/\sFirefox/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
```

This is only as good as the test user agents used, so please contribute your own in the comments!